# jquery submit form breaks js window.history.back()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, submit

when using an anchor and jquery to submit a form

```
<a id="submit_registration_form" href="#validate_form" >Submit</a> .... 
$('#submit_registration_form').click(function() {
    $('#registration_form').submit();
});
```

I can't come back to the previous page (where the data were submit) if i use

```
<a href="javascript:window.history.back();">Edit form</a>
```

In order for the history.back() to work, form must be submitted using a submit button

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

the probleme with input type submit button is that it is hard to style and get the same look as when using an anchor

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to remember to `return false` in the handler function to stop the link getting followed after click.

But it is much better to work on styling the submit button instead of abusing links, with the usability problems that brings. Some tips: `border: none`, `padding: 0`, `background: transparent`, `display: inline`, and for Firefox, `...::-moz-focus-inner { padding: 0; }`.

`history.back()` is also almost always the wrong thing (consider instead re-echoing the form contents in the new page), and `javascript:` URLs are to be avoided in all cases.

Comment: Huge thing to note is that `<button type="submit">` is far more flexible than `<input type="submit">`, and button can contain HTML (unlike input) should you need to do something fancy.

Comment: Yes, the same styling applies to both `input` and `button`. I'm ancient enough that I remember when `button` didn't exist so I default to `input` :-)

Comment: Well IE6 used to submit the `innerHTML` of `<button>` instead of `value`, which always made me afraid to use them. I seem to remember differences in what CSS could do to them, but maybe it was never true.

Comment: thanx guys, I stick with input buttons since they are js-hassel-free! and allows forms to be submit by hitting just "Enter".. I got to style them to look like they should, well at least in newer browser